# Parse JSON array with Json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

how can I read the JSON from this site (http://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/rest-api/v2/stations.json?includeTimeseries=true&includeCurrentMeasurement=true) in C# with the Json.net library?
In this JSon there is only a array. I tested it with this code, but it doesn't work.

```
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
  JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream));
  dynamic info = JObject.Load(reader);
}
```

If i debug this, then VS says that the item is not an object. I try it with `JArray.Load(reader);` but then I don't know how to access the items.

Comment: Do you want to use only Json.net library or some other library solution are acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `JArray.Load` is working correctly. The `JArray` then has a simple indexer to get to the individual items:

```
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
  var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream));
  var jsonArray = JArray.Load(reader);
  var item20 = jsonArray[19];
  var item20ShortName = (string)item20["shortname"];
}
```

Comment: @user2025830 Adjusted the answer.